# How to connect jquery chained to html or txt data

Tags: jquery, select, chained

I got question beacuse i novice in Jquery . I have this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
<script charset=utf-8>
  $(function(){
      $("#series").chained("#mark");
      $("#model").chained("#series");
  });
  </script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="chained">
<select id="mark" name="mark">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="Ciezarowe">Ciezarowe</option>
  <option value="Autobusy">Autobusy</option>
  <option value="Maszyny">Maszyny</option>
  <option value="Indywidualne">Indywidualne</option>
</select>
<select id="series" name="series">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="Ford" class="Ciezarowe">Ford</option>
  <option value="Mercedes" class="Ciezarowe">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Peugeot" class="Ciezarowe">Peugeot</option>
  <option value="Ikar" class="Autobusy">Ikar</option>
  <option value="Iveco" class="Autobusy">Iveco</option>
  <option value="Man" class="Autobusy">Man</option>
  <option value="Komatsu" class="Maszyny">Komatsu</option>
  <option value="Nissan" class="Maszyny">Nissan</option>
  <option value="Still" class="Maszyny">Still</option>
  <option value="Pojedyncze" class="Indywidualne">Pojedyncze</option>
  <option value="Grupowe" class="Indywidualne">Grupowe</option>
  <option value="Firmowe" class="Indywidualne">Firmowe</option>
</select>
<select id="model" name="model">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="F1" class="Ford">F1</option>
  <option value="F2" class="Ford">F2</option>
  <option value="F3" class="Ford">F3</option>
  <option value="S1" class="Mercedes">S1</option>
  <option value="S2" class="Mercedes">S2</option>
  <option value="S3" class="Mercedes">S3</option>
  <option value="P1" class="Peugeot">P1</option>
  <option value="P2" class="Peugeot">P2</option>
  <option value="P3" class="Peugeot">P3</option>
  <option value="I1" class="Ikar">I1</option>
  <option value="I2" class="Ikar">I2</option>
  <option value="I3" class="Ikar">I3</option>
  <option value="V1" class="Iveco">V1</option>
  <option value="V2" class="Iveco">V2</option>
  <option value="V3" class="Iveco">V3</option>
  <option value="M1" class="Man">M1</option>
  <option value="M2" class="Man">M2</option>
  <option value="M3" class="Mano">M3</option>
  <option value="K1" class="Komatsu">K1</option>
  <option value="K2" class="Komatsu">K2</option>
  <option value="K3" class="Komatsu">K3</option>
  <option value="N1" class="Nissan">N1</option>
  <option value="N2" class="Nissan">N2</option>
  <option value="N3" class="Nissan">N3</option>
  <option value="S1" class="Still">S1</option>
  <option value="S2" class="Still">S2</option>
  <option value="S3" class="Still">S3</option>
  <option value="P1" class="Pojedyncze">P1</option>
  <option value="P2" class="Pojedyncze">P2</option>
  <option value="P3" class="Pojedyncze">P3</option>
  <option value="G1" class="Grupowe">G1</option>
  <option value="G2" class="Grupowe">G2</option>
  <option value="G3" class="Grupowe">G3</option>
  <option value="F1" class="Firmowe">F1</option>
  <option value="F2" class="Firmowe">F2</option>
  <option value="F3" class="Firmowe">F3</option>
</select>
 <button id="button" type="submit">Wyszukaj</button>
 </div>
 <div class="search result">                     
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

My question is How can i connect jquery chained to html data or txt data ... 
I want to make this data in table and describe choose option from select and show result in div below ?
Can you give me some advice or tip how to do it?

Comment: And what table should be created? In response to what event(s) or interaction(s)?

Comment: For example  what i have now :
1.Car category choose city cars
2 Car mark category choose BMW
3.Car model category choose M3 

And then when i choose tier 3 select option in this example M3 i want to achive some text describing this model  below  it can by in tabel or not .
At this moment i have problem to connect  Jquery chained with this somekind of data text to load it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but if you'd like to display content based on their selection you could use jquery as such.

```
$(function(){
    $('#model').on('change', function(event){
        // $('.result').append("Mark: "+$('mark').val());
        // or...
        // $.ajax({});
    });
)};
```